# Dual representation matrix "recycling"

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Imagine we have $V$, a finite dimensional vector space endowed with an inner product and its dual space $V^*$. We have also a matrix Lie algebra and a representation of it, $\pi$, that acts on $V$. The book I am reading (Brian Hall's book on Lie groups) defines the dual representation

$\pi^* (x)=-\pi(x)^{Tr}$

Where $Tr$ stands by transpose. Now imagine we have a matrix for some $\pi(x_1)$               . To get a matrix representing $\pi(x_1)^*$ could I just minus transpose the matrix I have?

I understand that $\pi$ and $\pi^*$ don't act on the same vector space, but I figured that maybe a matrix for one could be used on the other (minus transposing it) and be thought of a matrix in the basis formed by the dual vectors of the basis used to compute the original matrix.